# Cuantas peticiones permite una hoja de cálculo de Google usada como base de datos en nodejs o php

Tags: nodejs, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Existen varios proyectos en GitHub que, utilizando las herramientas de desarrollo de Google, permiten tener acceso a una hoja de cálculo de Google. Por ejemplo está https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet-to-json en nodejs. ¿Cuántas peticiones permitirá Google por día?

Comment: No deberías de hacerlo ya que no te garantiza la integridad de tus datos. Y sí, seguramente alguien ya lo intentó, aunque no por ello es menos recomendable.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: jon_eldiablo : Este sitio tiene un modelo y comunidad muy particulares. Hay que evitar frases como "quisiera saber si alguien..." porque se presta a interpretar la pregunta como una basada principalmente en opiniones que en este sitio no se admiten. En este caso la pregunta se podía arreglar fácilmente, así que lo hice esperando que te sirva de ejemplo inicial. Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida sería muy bueno que incluyeras los buscado/investigado en relación al tema central de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits, Google Sheets API V4 tiene los siguientes límites

> Límite de 500 solicitudes por 100 segundos por proyecto, y 100 solicitudes por 100 segundos por usuario. Límites para lectura y escritura son monitoreado por separado. No hay un límite de uso diario.

NOTA: Algunos proyectos en GitHub como el referido por el OP hace uso a de APIs obsoletas que aún siguen "vivas" sin embargo, el propio Google recomienda fuertemente el uso de la versión actual que hoy día es la V4.

En la sección de guías de la documentación oficial se incluyen varios "quickstarts" (ejemplos sencillos), entre los que se encuentran las guías para Node.js, PHP entre otros.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, echaré un ojo.